# Error while replace string with symbol in Java

Tags: java, string

I'm solving this problem:
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gFxJ.png)

And what I did is this:

```
import java.io.*;
import static java.lang.System.exit;
import java.util.*;

//Driver for Abbreviations
public class AbbreviationsDriver {

//string of message
private static String message = "";
//List of Abbreviations
private static String[] AbbreviationsList;
//Abbreviations list file
private static File AbbreviationsListFile = new File("abbreviations.txt");
//message file
private static File inputMessageFile = new File("sample_msg.txt");

//output message file
private static File outputMessageFile = new File("sample_output.txt");

//main method
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    setAbbreviations(readFileList(AbbreviationsListFile));
    System.out.println("list of abbriviations:\n" + Arrays.toString(AbbreviationsList));
    setMessage(readFile(inputMessageFile));
    System.out.println("\nMessage in input file:\n" + message);
    writeFile(outputMessageFile,addTags(message, AbbreviationsList));
    System.out.println("\nMessage with tag in output file:\n" + addTags(message, AbbreviationsList));
}

//method to add tags
public static String addTags(String toTag, String[] abbreviations){
    for(String abbreviation:abbreviations)
        if(toTag.contains(abbreviation)){
            toTag = toTag.replaceAll(abbreviation, "<" + abbreviation + ">");
        }
    return toTag;
}

//method to read the file list
public static String[] readFileList(File fileInput){
    String input = "";
    try{
        Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(fileInput);
        while(inputStream.hasNextLine()){
            input = input + inputStream.nextLine()+ "<String>";
        }
        inputStream.close();
        //   System.out.println("list in string: " + input);
        return input.split("<String>");
    }
    catch(Exception exception){
        System.out.println("error in getting string array from file:\t" + exception.getMessage());
        exit(0);
        return new String[] {""};
    }
}

//method to read the file
public static String readFile(File fileInput){
    String inputFile = "";
    try{
        Scanner inputStatement = new Scanner(fileInput);
        while(inputStatement.hasNextLine()){
            inputFile = inputFile + inputStatement.nextLine();
        }
        inputStatement.close();
        return inputFile;
    }
    catch(Exception exception){
        System.out.println("error in getting message from file:\t" + exception.getMessage());
        exit(0);
        return "";
    }
}

//method to write the output file
public static void writeFile(File fileName, String outString){
    try{
        PrintWriter outputStatement = new PrintWriter(fileName);
        outputStatement.print(outString);
        outputStatement.close();
    }
    catch(Exception exception){
        System.out.println("error in setting message of file:\t" + exception.getMessage());
        exit(0);
    }
}

//method to set abbreviations
public static void setAbbreviations(String[] newAbbreviationsList){
    AbbreviationsList = newAbbreviationsList;
}

//setter to set message
public static void setMessage(String newMessage){
    message = newMessage;
}

//input string
public static String inputString(){
    return new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
}

}
```

abbreviations.txt is here:

```
lol
:)
iirc
4
u
ttfn
```

and sample_msg.txt is here:

```
How are u today? Iirc, this is your first free day. Hope you are having fun! :)
```

but when I compile and run, the error message comes out:

```
list of abbriviations:
[lol, :), iirc, 4, u, ttfn]

Message in input file:
How are u today? Iirc, this is your first free day. Hope you are having fun! :)
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unmatched closing ')' near index 0
:)
^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1969)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1706)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1352)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1028)
    at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2223)
    at AbbreviationsDriver.addTags(AbbreviationsDriver.java:44)
    at AbbreviationsDriver.main(AbbreviationsDriver.java:36)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I don't know how to solve this error because I've never seen this error before.
Please help me!

Comment: If you are not using regular expressions, use `string.replace()` instead of `string.replaceAll()`...

Comment: Please look at Java's regex [syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/regex/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 0):

You pass wrong parameter into replaceAll(). First parameter must be a regex. For your purpose, regex is not needed, so use replace() method instead.

Answer (score 0):

You faced the error because `)` is treated as a metacharacter in regex and therefore either it needs to be escaped or must be paired with its closing counterpart.

## Solution

You need to treat abbreviations with [metacharacters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/literals.html) and strings without metacharacters differently. For strings with metacharacters (e.g. `:)` where `)` is a metacharacter), you should use [String#replace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) while for the strings without metacharacter you should use [String#replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

When you use `String#replaceAll`, you should create a [capturing group](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html) which includes [word boundaries](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html) e.g. `(\bu\b)` so that only those `u` will be processed which appear as a word. Finally, you should replace the capturing group with `<$1>` where `$1` refers to the first (in the code given below, there is only one capturing group) capturing group e.g. `(\bu\b)` will be replaced by `<u>`.

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] abbrWithoutMetaChars = { "lol", "iirc", "4", "u", "ttfn" };
        String[] abbrWithMetaChars = { ":)" };

        // Test string
        String str = "How are u today? iirc, this is your first free day. Hope you are having fun! :)";

        // Replace all abbr. without meta chars
        for (String abbreviation : abbrWithoutMetaChars) {
            str = str.replaceAll("(\\b" + abbreviation + "\\b)", "<$1>");
        }

        // Replace all abbr. with meta chars
        for (String abbreviation : abbrWithMetaChars) {
            str = str.replace(abbreviation, "<" + abbreviation + ">");
        }

        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
How are <u> today? <iirc>, this is your first free day. Hope you are having fun! <:)>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is actually tricky. For example, in the list of abbreviations, `u` should be interpreted as a word and not a letter, since in your expected output you don't surround the letter *u* in the word *your* with angle brackets but only the *u* that appears by itself. Hence your code needs to locate the abbreviation as a single word in the input.

Also, *iirc* appears in the abbreviations list but in the input you have *Iirc* (with a capital *I*) and in the expected output it should appear as *<Iirc>* and not as *<iirc>*. In other words you should ignore case when locating the abbreviation but you need to keep the case after surrounding the abbreviation with angle brackets.

Then you have *:)* in the abbreviations list but *)* has special meaning in regular expression syntax so your code also needs to handle that situation.

All the above implies that you need to analyze the contents of the abbreviations list file in order to turn a raw abbreviation into a valid regular expression that you can then use to locate the abbreviation in the input text.

If you assume that the abbreviations list may contain every possible abbreviation, you would probably need a large amount of code to handle each one properly. Rather than do that, I just concentrated on your sample list which divides easily into two groups:

1. simple words
2. punctuation only

Note that the second group is also known as [emoticons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_emoticons) and some emoticons contain both letters and punctuation which my code, below, does not handle. As I said, my solution only pertains to your sample list of abbreviations.

Here is the code and below the code are some notes regarding it. Please not that I took the liberty of not just fixing your code, but refactoring it as well.

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;

//Driver for Abbreviations
public class AbbreviationsDriver {

//Abbreviations list file
    private static Path abbreviationsListPath = Paths.get("abbreviations.txt");
//message file
    private static Path inputPath = Paths.get("sample_msg.txt");

//output message file
    private static File outputMessageFile = new File("sample_output.txt");

//main method
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        List<String> abbreviationsList = readFileList(abbreviationsListPath);
        System.out.println("List of abbreviations: " + abbreviationsList);
        String message = readFile(inputPath);
        System.out.println("\nMessage in input file:\n" + message);
        String result = addTags(message, abbreviationsList);
        writeFile(outputMessageFile, result);
        System.out.println("\nMessage with tag in output file:\n" + result);
    }

//method to add tags
    public static String addTags(String toTag, List<String> abbreviations) {
        for (String abbreviation : abbreviations) {
            String regex;
            if (abbreviation.contains(")")) {
                regex = "(\\Q" + abbreviation + "\\E)";
            }
            else {
                regex = "(?i)(\\b" + abbreviation + "\\b)";
            }
            toTag = toTag.replaceAll(regex, "<$1>");
        }
        return toTag;
    }

//method to read the file list
    public static List<String> readFileList(Path path) {
        List<String> list;
        try {
            list = Files.readAllLines(path);
        }
        catch (IOException exception) {
            list = List.of();
            System.out.println("Failed to load: " + path);
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }

//method to read the file
    public static String readFile(Path path) {
        String inputFile;
        try {
            inputFile = Files.readString(path);
        }
        catch (IOException exception) {
            System.out.println("Failed to read: " + path);
            exception.printStackTrace();
            inputFile = "";
        }
        return inputFile;
    }

//method to write the output file
    public static void writeFile(File fileName, String outString) {
        try {
            PrintWriter outputStatement = new PrintWriter(fileName);
            outputStatement.print(outString);
            outputStatement.close();
        }
        catch (Exception exception) {
            System.out.println("Failed to write file: " + fileName);
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

- I use interface `Path` rather that class `File` so that I can use methods of class `Files` to read the text files that contain the abbreviations list and the input. Hence my code works with interface `List` rather than with an array of `String`.
- Passing class members to methods as method parameters defeats the purpose of having a class member in the first place. Hence I removed the members `message` and `AbbreviationsList`.
- The actual work of locating the abbreviations in the input and surrounding them with angle brackets, all occurs in method `addTags`. Here I handle each separate group of abbreviations. If the abbreviation contains the character *)*, I quote it by surrounding it with quote markers `\Q` and `\E`. (Refer to *javadoc* of class [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)). Otherwise the abbreviation is a regular word, so I surround it with the word boundary marker `\b`. I also enclose each regular expression in parentheses so as to make it a capturing group. Note that the second regular expression begins with `(?i)` which means to ignore case. Hence `iirc` will match `Iirc`.
- The replacement string is `<$1>`. The `$1` is replaced with the string that was actually matched so any abbreviation found in the input will be replaced by the matched string surrounded with angle brackets.

Finally, here is the output when running the above code and using your sample data.

```
List of abbreviations: [lol, :), iirc, 4, u, ttfn]

Message in input file:
How are u today? Iirc, this is your first free day. Hope you are having fun! :)

Message with tag in output file:
How are <u> today? <Iirc>, this is your first free day. Hope you are having fun! <:)>
```

Comment: when I try this code in intelliJ, some error comes out: List.of() & Files.readString(path) cannot be solved.

Comment: @JasonKim which java version are you using? I ran the code with JDK 14.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. Either you use regular expressions, or you do things the old-fashioned way by parsing word-by-word. Others have pointed out problems with your current code, due to using strings that contain regular expression metacharacters. In particular,

```
String doesNotWork = "I am :)".replaceAll(":)", "happy"); // invalid regex
```

This can be solved by *quoting* the string, so that metacharacters are converted into literals (it returns the string that would be written as `"\\Q:)\\E"`, because `\Q` and `\E` are used as delimiters for quoting whole substrings, as opposed to `\`, which quotes the next only if it is non-alphabetical; and is otherwise used for a host of regex classes):

```
String worksAsExpected = "I am :)".replaceAll(Pattern.quote(":)"), "happy");
```

The most efficient way to process text is to do a single pass. This can be achieved by combining literal expressions with `|`s:

```
    String regex = Stream.of("lol iirc 4".split(" "))
        .map(s -> Pattern.quote(s))         // quotes each emoticon
        .collect(Collectors.joining("|"));  // joins with |
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);
```

This yields surprisingly compact code, with nothing hardcoded. Finished code:

```
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
public class T {

    public static String mark(
           String[] needles, String startMark, String endMark, String input) {
        String regex = Stream.of(needles)
            .map(s -> s.matches("\\p{Alpha}+") ? // quotes each 
                        "\\b" + Pattern.quote(s) + "\\b" : // to avoid yo<u>r
                        Pattern.quote(s))                  // to handle emoticons
            .collect(Collectors.joining("|"));   // joins with |
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        while (m.find()) {
            m.appendReplacement(output, startMark + m.group() + endMark);
        }
        m.appendTail(output);
        return output.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String ... args) {
        System.out.println(mark(
            "lol iirc 4 u ttfn :)".split(" "),  // abbreviations 
            "<", ">",                           // markers to mark them with
            "How are u today? iirc, this is your first free day. "
            + "Hope you are having fun! :)"));
    }
}
```

I used [@Arvind's trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62645514/15472) of placing word-boundary metacharacters (`\\b`) only on alphabetical needles. This fixes all `u`s in words being marked; but may yield strange results for `4`s: writing a number with 4s in it will get it marked. Ultimately, natural language processing is hard. Regular expressions are great for very regular inputs.